# Duplicating Form Layout on Click

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a form that gives the user the option to add more fields to fill. The user adds more fields by clicking on a button. When the button is clicked It duplicates a RelativeLayout that houses form elements in it inside of another RelativeLayout.

This is the form that I'm trying to duplicate

```
<RelativeLayout
    android1:id="@+id/questionTemplate"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="60dp"
    android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android1:layout_below="@+id/TextView01" 
>

<Button
    android1:id="@+id/Button02"
    android1:layout_width="75dp"
    android1:layout_height="20dp"
    android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android1:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android1:background="@drawable/purplebutton"
    android1:text="BROWSE"
    android1:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
    android1:textSize="10sp" 
/>

<EditText
    android1:id="@+id/EditText02"
    android1:layout_width="match_parent"
    android1:layout_height="25dp"
    android1:layout_above="@+id/Button02"
    android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android1:background="@drawable/textlines"
    android1:ems="10"
    android1:hint="50 WORDS OR LESS"
    android1:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android1:paddingLeft="5dp" 
    >

<requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android1:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android1:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android1:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button02"
    android1:text="ADD PICTURE OR VIDEO"
    android1:textSize="10sp" 
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Its inside another RelativeLayout with an id of "questionsContainer". And when the user clicks on a button with an id of "makeLayoutButton" its supposed to add another instance of "questionTemplate" below another one.

Here's what I'm doing when the user clicks on the button

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Toast toast;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.makeLayoutButton:


        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v1 = vi.inflate(R.layout.make_question, null);


        // template to be copied
        RelativeLayout target = (RelativeLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.questionTemplate);

        // insert into main view
        RelativeLayout insertPoint = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.questionsContainer);

        insertPoint.addView(target);


        break;

    }
}
```

But it keeps crashing and the log informs me that I need to call removeView on the parent first. But when I do that it just removes all the children of the container and leaves me with one copy of the form without it duplicating. Any clues as to where I'm going wrong? I have a feeling it has something to do ids.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the output is correct. You're trying to add a `View` which already exists. You don't create (duplicate) new `View` but use the existing one by using `findViewById()` method.

In order to create the actual `View`, you should use `inflate()` method:

```
RelativeLayout target = (RelativeLayout) v1.inflate(R.id.questionTemplate, null); // if v1 is container for this R.id.questionTemplate layout
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Frisbetarian Just replace your `RelativeLayout target = (RelativeLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.questionTemplate);` with what I wrote.

Comment: @Frisbetarian Try `RelativeLayout target = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.questionTemplate, v1);` instead. If you still get the `NullPointerException`, please post the trace from LogCat.

Comment: Eclipse keeps telling me that I need to cast argument'v1' to ViewGroup and when I do that the app crashes with a null pointer exception.

Comment: @Frisbetarian Oh, you can't cast to `ViewGroup` if it's not a `ViewGroup`. That's why it crashes. What kind of `View` is this `R.layout.make_question`? Is it `RelativeLayout`, or what?

Comment: make_question is a an xml file in the res folder.

Comment: @Frisbetarian Ok, but what is the most external layout in this xml file? Is it `RelativeLayout`? If so, please do `RelativeLayout v1 = (RelativeLayout)vi.inflate(R.layout.make_question, null);` instead of `View v1 = vi.inflate(R.layout.make_question, null);`. If it's `LinearLayout` or anything else, just change my `RelativeLayout` to whatever type your layout is.